# how to identify specific strings and remove them inside a column

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<-structure(list(names = c("hdgdsa", "hsgdhs", "gt", "gdtdtdf", 
"gdtdtdf", "hdgdy", "hjddg", "hdyeye", "hss", "ufury", "hdydfg", 
"hdgdfs", "hdyft", "Probleusys", "Trialayy", "gentigle; jduhd7", 
"Qydyfg"), Modifications = c("1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S11(100)]", 
"1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 2xPhospho [S11(100); S13(100)]", "1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 2xPhospho [S3(100); S14(100)]", 
"1xCarbamidomethyl [C1]; 1xTMT6plex [K31]; 1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S22(100)]", 
"1xTMT6plex [K1]; 1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]", 
"1xTMT6plex [K4]; 1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]", 
"1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 2xPhospho [S10(100); S11(100)]", "1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 2xPhospho [S10(100); S11(100)]", 
"1xOxidation [M10]; 3xCarbamidomethyl [C8,C10,C19];1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S6(100)]", 
"1xOxidation [M14]; 1xTMT6plex [K4]; 1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]", 
"1xTMT6plex [K20]; 1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S10(100)]", 
"1xOxidation [M11]; 2xCarbamidomethyl [C8,C19];1xTMT6plex [K1]; 1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]", 
"1xTMT6plex [N-Term];1xCarbamidomethyl [C8]; 2xPhospho [S7(100); S8(100)]", 
"1xOxidation [M14]; 1xTMT6plex [K4]; 1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]", 
"1xTMT6plex [K20]; 1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 1xPhospho [S10(100)]", 
"1xOxidation [M11]; 2xCarbamidomethyl [C8,C19];1xTMT6plex [K1]; 1xTMT6plex [N-Term]; 2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]", 
"1xTMT6plex [N-Term];1xCarbamidomethyl [C8]; 2xPhospho [S7(100); S8(100)]"
), Numbers = c(482L, 454L, 355L, 309L, 282L, 280L, 273L, 196L, 
186L, 185L, 169L, 166L, 153L, 185L, 169L, 166L, 153L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-17L))
```

I am trying to remove part of modifications column, I want to remove all whatever in that column except those that have phospho

so the output look like this

```
names             Modifications                     Numbers
hdgdsa           1xPhospho [S11(100)]               482
hsgdhs           2xPhospho [S11(100); S13(100)]     454
gt               2xPhospho [S3(100); S14(100)]      355
gdtdtdf          1xPhospho [S22(100)]               309
gdtdtdf          2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]       282
hdgdy            2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]      280
hjddg            2xPhospho [S10(100); S11(100)]     273
hdyeye           2xPhospho [S10(100); S11(100)]     196
hss              1xPhospho [S6(100)]                186
ufury            2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]      185
hdydfg           1xPhospho [S10(100)]               169
hdgdfs           2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]       166
hdyft            2xPhospho [S7(100); S8(100)]       153
Probleusys       2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]      185
Trialayy         1xPhospho [S10(100)]               169
gentigle; jduhd7     2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]   166
Qydyfg           2xPhospho [S7(100); S8(100)]       153
```

for instance first this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `sub` from `base R` to match characters (`.*`) till a `;` and one or more spaces (`\\s+`), capture the word (`\\w+`) followed by "Phospho" subtring and the rest of the characters (`.*`) as a group (`(...)`) and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
df$Modifications <- sub(".*;\\s+(\\w+Phospho.*)", "\\1", df$Modifications)
```

-output

```
df
              names                  Modifications Numbers
1            hdgdsa           1xPhospho [S11(100)]     482
2            hsgdhs 2xPhospho [S11(100); S13(100)]     454
3                gt  2xPhospho [S3(100); S14(100)]     355
4           gdtdtdf           1xPhospho [S22(100)]     309
5           gdtdtdf   2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]     282
6             hdgdy  2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]     280
7             hjddg 2xPhospho [S10(100); S11(100)]     273
8            hdyeye 2xPhospho [S10(100); S11(100)]     196
9               hss            1xPhospho [S6(100)]     186
10            ufury  2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]     185
11           hdydfg           1xPhospho [S10(100)]     169
12           hdgdfs   2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]     166
13            hdyft   2xPhospho [S7(100); S8(100)]     153
14       Probleusys  2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]     185
15         Trialayy           1xPhospho [S10(100)]     169
16 gentigle; jduhd7   2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]     166
17           Qydyfg   2xPhospho [S7(100); S8(100)]     153
```

If we want to remove the rows having no 'Phospho', use `grepl` with `subset` (there was no case in the example though)

```
subset(df, grepl('Phospho', Modifications))
```

---

If we need to remove substrings one a time, an option is to split the string with `separate_rows` and then do a group by `paste`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   separate_rows(Modifications, sep = ";\\s*") %>% 
   filter(str_detect(Modifications, "TMT", negate = TRUE)) %>% 
   group_by(rn, names, Numbers) %>%
   summarise(Modifications = str_c(Modifications, collapse="; "), 
            .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 17 x 3
   names            Numbers Modifications                                                              
   <chr>              <int> <chr>                                                                      
 1 hdgdsa               482 1xPhospho [S11(100)]                                                       
 2 hsgdhs               454 2xPhospho [S11(100); S13(100)]                                             
 3 gt                   355 2xPhospho [S3(100); S14(100)]                                              
 4 gdtdtdf              309 1xCarbamidomethyl [C1]; 1xPhospho [S22(100)]                               
 5 gdtdtdf              282 2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]                                               
 6 hdgdy                280 2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]                                              
 7 hjddg                273 2xPhospho [S10(100); S11(100)]                                             
 8 hdyeye               196 2xPhospho [S10(100); S11(100)]                                             
 9 hss                  186 1xOxidation [M10]; 3xCarbamidomethyl [C8,C10,C19]; 1xPhospho [S6(100)]     
10 ufury                185 1xOxidation [M14]; 2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]                           
11 hdydfg               169 1xPhospho [S10(100)]                                                       
12 hdgdfs               166 1xOxidation [M11]; 2xCarbamidomethyl [C8,C19]; 2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]
13 hdyft                153 1xCarbamidomethyl [C8]; 2xPhospho [S7(100); S8(100)]                       
14 Probleusys           185 1xOxidation [M14]; 2xPhospho [S7(100); S10(100)]                           
15 Trialayy             169 1xPhospho [S10(100)]                                                       
16 gentigle; jduhd7     166 1xOxidation [M11]; 2xCarbamidomethyl [C8,C19]; 2xPhospho [S4(100); S7(100)]
17 Qydyfg               153 1xCarbamidomethyl [C8]; 2xPhospho [S7(100); S8(100)]
```

Comment: thank you man, so amazing, would you mind making it in a way that in each step removes one set ? and then for instance I will have oxidation and phospho... I will accept it anyway because it gives me what I want

Comment: @Learner Can you show the expected output in your post.  It is not clear from the comments. thanks

Comment: I just added one example for instance at first get rid of TMT, then get rid of Oxidation, then get rid of carbodemytelation and then the last output is the best output

Comment: @Learner is the image showed the expected output

Comment: @Learner if that is the case, you may split the string into long format with `separate_rows` and then remove whatever you don't want i..e `df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% separate_rows(Modifications, sep = ";\\s+") %>% filter(str_detect(Modifications, "TMT", negate = TRUE))`

Comment: @Learner please check, i updatd the post

Comment: thanks I liked your answer, I am just curious to remove the strings in each step but the first output was what I wanted anyway

Comment: @Learner In the updated solutioin I showed to remove a single rows of TMT.  If you want to remove multiple, then use `"TMT|Carbamidomethy"` in `str_detect`

Comment: thank you so much , I am wondering if you know how to remove the certain rows that have only NA? I mean all are NA? I tried `df[is.na,]` but it does not work

Comment: @Learner You can do `subset(df, rowSums(is.na(df)) < ncol(df))`